# How to reload page with json correctly with timer in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, reloaddata

I am using swift 3 and I have a table view that loads data from json. The problem is when I am going to another page and come back to the home page the data won't load again some times. I asked this question and one of my friend told me to use timer because you need to reload your tableView so you need to remove all of the data on tableview and then using json again and then reload the tableview so this will take some seconds so I used remove all data in table view and used timer about 2 seconds and then download json and reload table view But some times it doesn't work properly - some times the data didn't remove or some times all data will remove and I can't see any thing

my codes are so huge so I just write necessary codes here

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

     let refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(Home2ViewController.refreshFunction) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

     refreshFunction()

     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {

         refreshTimer.invalidate()

     })


func refreshFunction() {
    NSLog("refreshFunction")
    print("refreshing!")

    ////////////////////// Get Home Page

    EmailSignInViewController.step.removeAll()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
    let urlPath3: String = "http://mamamoniya.com/api/orders?api_token=\(EmailSignInViewController.api_token)"

    let url3: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath3)!
    let request3: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url3 as URL)

    request3.httpMethod = "GET"

    let queue3:OperationQueue = OperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request3 as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

        do {
            if let jsonResult3 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? Array<Any> {

                for item in jsonResult3 {

                    if let dict = item as?  NSDictionary {
                        if let step = dict.value(forKey: "step"){
                            EmailSignInViewController.step.append(step as! Int)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    //////////////////End Get


    self.customTableView.reloadData()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
            self.waitingSpinner.stopAnimating()
            self.waitingTitle.textColor = UIColor.clear
        })

    })

}
```

**for some reasons I can't write real url here But you can use any url as you know**

Comment: Why you are using timer ? Just call your service and when you get responce simply update your data source and reload the tableView.

Comment: the tableview didn't reload correctly so I removed all data and append new data to tableview and this will take some seconds so I used timer because removing data and adding new data will take time

Comment: you can reload data in ViewWillAppear method.

Comment: I want to use some thing like promise method in my codes